# Change domain "local" in avahi and and use a hostname with multiple labels

Tags: dns, systemctl, mdns, zeroconf, avahi

I need to publish multiple addresses for the same IP (eg: address1.local, address2.local)

Did it creating a service `/etc/systemd/system/avahi-alias@.service` with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Publish %I as alias for %H.local via mdns

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/avahi-publish -a -R %I $(avahi-resolve -4 -n %H.local | cut -f 2)"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then if I run:
`sudo systemctl enable --now avahi-alias@address1.local.service`
`sudo systemctl enable --now avahi-alias@address2.local.service`
It works perfect.

But now if I need to extend it to publish eg: `address1.something.otherdomain` I have error publishing.
Tried different ways, changing the `avahi-daemon.conf` for example and didn't work for me.

I will appreciate any help you can give me.

Kind regards

**EDITED:**
Using this solution: https://github.com/george-hawkins/avahi-aliases-notes
I can handle the use of multiple labels on the cname. But still without being able to change ".local" by something else.